# ruby string formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-formatting

I'm trying to do some string formatting. I've tried with 'insert' but that is obviously wrong. I only need the formatting.

```
t = 123456789
```

I want t to be formatted in: 1234.56.789

So, including the two dots. What is the best way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: so what you're saying is that you always want 4 digits, a period, 2 more digits, another period and three final digits? Or is there some other logic to the placement of the periods?

Comment: nope, it's always. After the 4th & 6th. I used to do: t.insert(4,'.').insert(7,'.') but of course that's a bit wrong.. i'm looking for the formatting option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extend the class

```
class String
  def right_format
    self.clone.insert(4,'.').insert(7,'.')
  end
end
```

i.e. inject a method

Comment: ure the man! thx! forgot that i could clone it of course... darn :)